# How to find server real IP

Tags: go

How do I find the public IP address of the machine or server my program is running on?

Like when the program is executed it detect the public of the server and print for e.g.`running at 123.45.67.89`

Comment: `net.InterfaceAddrs` will return all addresses.

Comment: But `net.InterfaceAddrs` may not actually have your public ip. In a typical home or cloud environment, the system on which you are running will have a private address, and your publicly visible ip is hosted on a router somewhere else.

Comment: That is not something you can discover in a portable way afaik.

Comment: you ask a peer to tell you the ip it has seen when you requested him something. But f you have many IPs, very regular with the dual stack ipv6/ipv4, their might b multiple answers depending who you ask, how you ask. And we are jst talking about the "regular" day to day internet...

Comment: Private IP addresses _are_ real IP addresses. IPv4 has no distinction between Private and public addresses. To IPv4, they are just addresses. Private IPv4 addresses are simply arbitrarily chosen address ranges that the ISPs have agreed not to route between them on the public Internet, but it is _not_ part of the IPv4 protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no method guaranteed to return your "public" ip address.

---

The first question is, what is your public ip address? The address of your machine, as seen by the system to which you are connecting, may vary depending on how your local Internet service is configured and on the service to which you're connecting:

- As I mentioned in a comment, in a typical home environment your machine doesn't *have* a public ip address. The public address is hosted by your router.
- If you're accessing a service through a proxy or vpn, your machine's address may be entirely different from when you're directly connecting to a service.
- On a system with multiple interfaces, the origin address selected may depend upon the address to which  you are connecting: different addresses may have different routes.

You can try using a service like http://icanhazip.com/ to try to determine your public ip. This will be correct in many but not all situations.

Answer (score 2):

public IP address is a vague notion, in practice, it might or might not be a static address. What do you know about that ? It is just a endpoint valid for a certain amount of time, which depends on many factors like which interface was used to issue the query.

We can use the [mainline bittorrent dht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT) to give us some indications.

The Go language provides the cool [dht package](https://github.com/anacrolix/dht) written by [anacrolix](https://github.com/anacrolix).

When querying nodes with a `find_peers` verb we receive a packet containing the remote ip address the peer has associated with our query. This is described in [bep10](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0010.html).

If an UDP connection is not a good option, you might opt for a query to [bittorent trackers](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) as described in [bep24](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0024.html)

Consider that peers might be malicious, thus the more results, the better.

Below program outputs the list of external network addresses associated with the computer initiating the query from the POV of the cohort of nodes queried.

Addresses are scored by the numbers of response.

read also https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

```
found 9 bootstrap peers
found 6 peers
4    [2001:861:51c5:xxx:40d1:8061:1fe0:xxx]:9090
2    81.96.42.191:9090
```

- `4` peers told us that we were using `[2001:861:51c5:xxx:40d1:8061:1fe0:xxx]:9090`, we can infer this is ipv6.
- `2` of them told we were using `81.96.42.191:9090`, the ipv4 interface.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/anacrolix/dht"
    "github.com/anacrolix/dht/krpc"
    "github.com/anacrolix/torrent/bencode"
)

var maxTimeout = time.Second * 5

func main() {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("db.json")
    var rawAddrs []string
    json.Unmarshal(b, &rawAddrs)
    defer func() {
        if len(rawAddrs) < 1 {
            return
        }
        if len(rawAddrs) > 30 {
            rawAddrs = rawAddrs[:30]
        }
        buf, err := json.Marshal(rawAddrs)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = ioutil.WriteFile("db.json", buf, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%v peers recorded\n", len(rawAddrs))
    }()
    bootstrap, err := parseAddrs(rawAddrs)
    if err != nil {
        bootstrap, err = globalBootstrapAddrs()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    findPeers := []byte(`d1:ad2:id20:abcdefghij01234567899:info_hash20:mnopqrstuvwxyz123456e1:q9:get_peers1:t2:aa1:y1:qe`)

    local, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:9090")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ln, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", local)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    addrscores := map[string]int{}

    var drain drain
    defer drain.Wait()
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "found %v bootstrap peers\n", len(bootstrap))
    res, errs := readResponses(ln, len(bootstrap), sendQuery(ln, bootstrap, findPeers))
    drain.Errors(errs)

    peers := []net.Addr{}
    for d := range res {
        if isValidAddr(d.IP.UDP()) {
            addrscores[d.IP.String()]++
            d.R.ForAllNodes(func(arg1 krpc.NodeInfo) {
                peers = append(peers, arg1.Addr.UDP())
            })
        }
    }

    if len(peers) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "found %v peers\n", len(peers))
        res, errs = readResponses(ln, len(peers), sendQuery(ln, peers, findPeers))
        drain.Errors(errs)
        for d := range res {
            if isValidAddr(d.IP.UDP()) {
                addrscores[d.IP.String()]++
            }
        }
    }

    for _, peer := range peers {
        if isValidAddr(peer) {
            rawAddrs = append(rawAddrs, peer.String())
        }
    }

    addrs := make([]string, 0, len(addrscores))
    for addr := range addrscores {
        addrs = append(addrs, addr)
    }
    sort.Slice(addrs, func(i int, j int) bool {
        return addrscores[addrs[i]] > addrscores[addrs[j]]
    })

    for _, addr := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%-4v %v\n", addrscores[addr], addr)
    }
}

type drain struct{ sync.WaitGroup }

func (d *drain) Errors(errs <-chan error) {
    d.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer d.Done()
        for err := range errs {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        }
    }()
}

func parseAddrs(rawAddrs []string) (addrs []net.Addr, err error) {
    for _, s := range rawAddrs {
        host, port, err := net.SplitHostPort(s)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        ua, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", net.JoinHostPort(host, port))
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error resolving %q: %v", host, err)
            continue
        }
        addrs = append(addrs, ua)
    }
    if len(addrs) == 0 {
        err = errors.New("nothing resolved")
    }
    return
}

func globalBootstrapAddrs() (addrs []net.Addr, err error) {
    bootstrap, err := dht.GlobalBootstrapAddrs("udp")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, b := range bootstrap {
        addrs = append(addrs, b.Raw())
    }
    return
}

func isValidAddr(addr net.Addr) bool { // so weird guys.
    return addr.String() != "<nil>" && addr.String() != ":0"
}

func sendQuery(ln *net.UDPConn, peers []net.Addr, query []byte) chan error {
    errs := make(chan error)

    for _, addr := range peers {
        go func(addr net.Addr) {
            _, err := ln.WriteTo(query, addr)
            if err != nil {
                errs <- addressedError{Op: "send", error: err, Addr: addr}
            }
        }(addr)
    }

    return errs
}

func readResponses(ln *net.UDPConn, count int, errs chan error) (<-chan krpc.Msg, <-chan error) {

    data := make(chan krpc.Msg)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            buf := make([]byte, 1000)
            ln.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(maxTimeout))
            n, remoteAddr, err := ln.ReadFromUDP(buf)
            if err != nil {
                errs <- addressedError{Op: "rcv", error: err, Addr: remoteAddr}
                return
            }
            var m krpc.Msg
            err = bencode.Unmarshal(buf[:n], &m)
            if err != nil {
                errs <- addressedError{Op: "rcv", error: err, Addr: remoteAddr}
                return
            }
            data <- m
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(errs)
        close(data)
    }()

    return data, errs
}

type addressedError struct {
    error
    Op   string
    Addr net.Addr
}

func (a addressedError) Error() string {
    if !isValidAddr(a.Addr) {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%-5v %v", a.Op, a.error.Error())
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%-5v %v: %v", a.Op, a.Addr.String(), a.error.Error())
}
```